# Angularjs: radio button checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build a color configurator in AngularJS using radio buttons and everything seems to be working, the data binds, etc... but **I'm not able to set the default color radio button checked**. As I see in the docs if the ng-model is the same as the radio value the input should be auto-checked but I don't know if this only work for strings and not for objects.

This is the HTML:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="ThingControl">
    <ul >
        <li ng-repeat="color in colors">
            <input type="radio" ng-model="thing.color" value="{{color}}" />{{ color.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
    Preview: {{ thing }}
</div>
```

And this is the JS:

```
function ThingControl($scope){
    $scope.colors = [
        { name: "White", hex: "#ffffff"},
        { name: "Black", hex: "#000000"}
        ]

    $scope.thing = {
        color: $scope.colors[1]
    }

}
```

You can see the previous example in this fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/xWWwT/1/

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Selection is matched by the **string** defined in Value, so you can either do

```
value="{{color.name}}"

$scope.thing = {
    color: $scope.colors[1].name
}
```

or

```
value="{{color}}"

$scope.thing = {
    color: JSON.stringify($scope.colors[1])
}
```

As @bertez mentioned, use `ng-value` is the best solution.

```
ng-value="color"
```

Comment: Yes, your solution works as the value and model are strings, but if I do it your way I only bind the color name to the thing object :( as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/xWWwT/4/

Comment: @bertez Try the 2nd solution.

Comment: Finally somebody called dmco in the IRC found the solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/xWWwT/6/

    <input type="radio" ng-model="thing.color" ng-value="color" />

Using ng-value! :)

Comment: Why for example is this also working perfectly but it doesn’t when the type=‘radio’ ??? <input type='checkbox' ng-init='checkStatus=false' ng-model='checkStatus' ng-click='doIfChecked(checkStatus)'>

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried **ng-change** directive? You can use a expression to set it checked, try this.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="ThingControl">
<ul >
    <li ng-repeat="color in colors">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="thing.color" value="{{color}}" ng-checked="$index == 0" />{{ color.name }}
    </li>
</ul>
Preview: {{ thing }}
</div>
```

Comment: This is the only thing that works for me. Not ng-model nor ng-value.