# Angularjs multiple radio button, auto-select if only one is present

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

Am successful in building angularjs app of multiple dependent radio button.

But have a requirement to default select a radio button if only one is present.

Tried out the stuff in [Angularjs: radio button checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518251/angularjs-radio-button-checked), but it doesn't work for multiple radio buttons.

Code Explanation:

HTML Code:
I have two radio buttons. Second set of radio buttons are generated based on the first.

```
<div>
            <ul >
              <li> Part One : </li>
                        <li ng-repeat="f in Input"><input type="radio" name="oneInput" ng-value="f" ng-model="$parent.One">&nbsp;{{f.Name}}&nbsp;</input></li>
    </ul>
    </div><br/>
    <div>
              <ul>
                  <li> Part Two : </li>
                  <li ng-repeat="u in filteredUser = (One.User | filter: { Valid: 'Y' })"><input type="radio" name="userInput" ng-value="u" ng-model="$parent.Two">&nbsp;{{u.Name}}&nbsp;</input></li>
            </ul>
    </div><br/>
```

If I select a radio button in first set, and second set has only one radio button, it must be selected by default.

For example, if I select D, I get the D2 radio button which must be selected.

Complete Code @ http://plnkr.co/edit/dY2syxNWobxHpiVKIuux?p=preview

Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/QVvN6rP3wlyxbOJaAGHQ?p=preview

```
 $scope.$watch('One', function(value) {

    if (value.Name) {

      var users = $filter('filter')($scope.Input, value);

      var vaildUsers = $filter('filter')(users[0].User, {
        Valid: "Y"
      });


      if (vaildUsers.length == 1) {

        $scope.Two = vaildUsers[0];

      } else

      {

        $scope.Two = {};

      }
    }

  });
```